# Loading specific properties from the object in EF C# query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Please see the following query:

```
Blogs = await _context.Blog
            .Include(b => b.Owner)
            .ToListAsync();
```

this query will load all the blogs and the Owner (User object) of each blog, how i can load specific fields from the Owener object ?

for example i want only to load Owner.Name and Owener.ID  , i don't need to the other info (Email, Phone, Password, ....)

Comment: They will be loaded all together, however you may only select those You needed

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it manually;

```
var someData = await (
        from blog in _context.Blog
        join owner in _context.Users on blog.OwnerID equals owner.ID
        select new { Text = blog.Text, OwnerName = owner.Name}) //select whatever you want
        .ToListAsync();
```

This ensures only the data requested is "loaded" from the database.

---

Another option is to select from your query, if you are using lazy loading, this will not ensure the data isn't queried from the database:

```
var someData = await _context.Blog
        .Include(b => b.Owner)
        .Select(c => new { Text = c.Text, OwnerName = c.Owner.Name}) //select what needed
        .ToListAsync();
```

---

Since your case directly selects the data, the include is not necessary:

```
var someData = await _context.Blog
        .Select(c => new { Text = c.Text, OwnerName = c.Owner.Name}) //select what needed
        .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Select* like this:

```
Blogs = await _context.Blog
            .Include(b => b.Owner)
            .Select(x => new {x.Owner.ID, x.Owner.Name})
            .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Blogs = await _context.Blog
            .Include(b => b.Owner)
            .Select(b => new
            {
              Name = b.Name,
              Id = b.OwnerID
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```